# How to print a proper parse tree in console using Java?

Tags: java, compiler-construction, parse-tree

I am writing a program that simulates the 6 compiler phases using java. Currently, stuck in the printing of the parse tree in the 2nd phase, syntax Analyzer. I already know what my problem is after some debugging. The parent and children nodes are correct but is visually displayed in wrong depths.

Input: `z=y*y+x*3`

When it gets to the * symbol which has children, it displays its children first before displaying the its sibling node which is also another *, because of the recursion.

```
    public static void displayParseTree(ParseTreeNode node, int depth) {
        if (node != null) {
            StringBuilder indent = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < depth; i++) {
                indent.append(" ");
            }

            //if node has children print / -> child1  \ -> child2
            System.out.print(indent.toString() + node.token.getValue());
            // Check if the node has any children.
            if (!node.children.isEmpty()) {

                System.out.println("");
                
                System.out.print("/  ");
                System.out.println(" \\");

                // Print the left child node.
                displayParseTree(node.children.get(0), depth + 1);

                // Print the right child node.
                displayParseTree(node.children.get(1), depth + 1);
                System.out.println("");
            }
        }
    }
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrwPy.png)

Incase img doesn't open, this is the my current ouput:

```
Please enter the source code: 
z=y*y+x*3
Source Form: z=y*y+x*3
Math Form: z=yxy+xx3
Lexical Analyzer: id1=id2*id2+id3*3
Syntax analysis completed. The input is valid.

=
/   \
 id1 +
/   \
  *
/   \
   id2   id2
  *
/   \
   id3   3
```

I want my output to look more like this:

```
    =
  /  \
id1   +
    /    \
  *        *
/    \   /   \
id2  id2 id3  3
```

EDIT: I somewhat hardcoded it(not proud of it), but I'll leave it at that till I find a better way

```
    public static void displayParseTree(ParseTreeNode node, int depth) {
        if (node != null) {
            StringBuilder indent = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < depth; i++) {
                indent.append(" ");
            }

//if node has children print / -> child1  \ -> child2
            if (node.token.getValue().equals("=")){
                System.out.println("  " + indent.toString() + node.token.getValue());
            }

            // Check if the node has any children.
            if (!node.children.isEmpty()) {

                if (node.children.get(0).token.getValue().equals("*") && node.children.get(1).token.getValue().equals("*")) {
                    System.out.print("/  ");
                    System.out.println(" \\");

                    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                        System.out.print(node.children.get(i).token.getValue() + "  ");
                    }
                    System.out.println("");

                    System.out.print("/  ");
                    System.out.print(" \\   ");
                    System.out.print("  /  ");
                    System.out.println(" \\");

                    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
                        System.out.print(node.children.get(i).children.get(j).token.getValue() + "  ");
                    }
                    System.out.println("");
                }
                else {
                    // Print the left child node.
                    System.out.print("/  ");
                    System.out.println(" \\");

                    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                        System.out.print(node.children.get(i).token.getValue() + "  ");
                    }
                    System.out.println("");

                    displayParseTree(node.children.get(0), depth + 1);

                    // Print the right child node.
                    displayParseTree(node.children.get(1), depth + 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Current Output:

```
      =
    /   \
    id1  +  
    /   \
    *  *  
    /   \     /   \
    id2  id2  id3  3
```

Comment: The indent on the upper level depends on the bottom levels. A tree with right-only children will have a 0 indent at the root, regardless of the depth, whereas a left-only tree will have deepest indent at the root level. You can traverse you tree once to calculate assign indent to each node but that require recalculations after any tree change, not sure how relevant is that.

Comment: How would the indent of the upper level be affected by the bottom levels? I believe it's the opposite. Also, this tree does have left and right children. I don't exactly understand this last part. Traverse my tree once to calculate and assign indent to each node first? Then it should recalculate every time a new node is added?

Comment: The indent on the upper level does depend on the location where the items in the bottom level are. Just replace identifiers id2, id3 with longer names -> the bottom line will change, the operator in the line above needs to be centered etc.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured it out. Though I think there could've been a better solution, but this is what I managed to come up with.
Since, only the multiply and divide operators can come at the same depth so I just made a condition specifically for them. First check that both ops are * or /, if yes print the / \ branches and then print the ops, then print branches for all their children which is 4 so / \ / \ then using a nested loop print both of their children on the same line, else do everything normally. That's it. After that it was just a matter of adjusting the spaces to get the output I was looking for.

```
    public static void displayParseTree(ParseTreeNode node, int depth) {
        if (node != null) {
            StringBuilder indent = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < depth; i++) {
                indent.append(" ");
            }

//if node has children print / -> child1  \ -> child2
            if (node.token.getValue().equals("=")){
                System.out.println("       " + indent.toString() + node.token.getValue());
            }

            // Check if the node has any children.
            if (!node.children.isEmpty()) {

                if (node.children.get(0).token.getValue().equals("*") && node.children.get(1).token.getValue().equals("*") ||
                        node.children.get(0).token.getValue().equals("/") && node.children.get(1).token.getValue().equals("/")) {
                    System.out.print("        /   ");
                    System.out.println("  \\");

                    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                        System.out.print("     "+ node.children.get(i).token.getValue() + "    ");
                    }
                    System.out.println("");

                    System.out.print("   /  ");
                    System.out.print(" \\   ");
                    System.out.print("  /  ");
                    System.out.println(" \\");

                    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
                        System.out.print(" "+ node.children.get(i).children.get(j).token.getValue() + "  ");
                    }
                    System.out.println("");
                }
                else {
                    // Print the left child node.
                    System.out.print("   /  ");
                    System.out.println("    \\");

                    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                        System.out.print("  " + node.children.get(i).token.getValue() + "    ");
                    }
                    System.out.println("");

                    displayParseTree(node.children.get(0), depth + 1);

                    // Print the right child node.
                    displayParseTree(node.children.get(1), depth + 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

```
Please enter the source code: 
z=y*y+x*3
Source Form: z=y*y+x*3
Math Form: z=yxy+xx3
Lexical Analyzer: id1=id2*id2+id3*3
Syntax analysis completed. The input is valid.
       =
   /      \
  id1      +    
        /     \
     *         *    
   /   \     /   \
 id2   id2   id3   3
```

Comment: “only the multiply and divide operators can come at the same depth”: this cases being true the moment you use parentheses. Find a general solution.